# How does NumPy solve least squares for underdetermined systems?

Tags: least-squares, linear-algebra, numpy

Let's say that we have X of shape (2, 5)
and y of shape (2,)

This works: `np.linalg.lstsq(X, y)`

We would expect this to work only if X was of shape (N,5) where N>=5
But why and how?

We do get back 5 weights as expected but how is this problem solved?

Isn't it like we have 2 equations and 5 unknowns?
How could numpy solve this?
It must do something like interpolation to create more artificial equations?..

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? An undetermined system has many solutions.

Comment: Do you might have a link to relevant theory?..

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879411/what-is-the-most-accurate-method-in-python-for-computing-the-minimum-norm-soluti

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My understanding is that [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) relies on the [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) routine [dgelsd](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgelsd.f.html).

The problem is to solve:

$$ \text{minimize} (\text{over} \; \mathbf{x}) \quad  \| A\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} \|_2$$

Of course, this does not have a *unique* solution for a matrix A whose [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) is less than length of vector $\mathbf{b}$. In the case of an undetermined system, `dgelsd` provides a solution $\mathbf{z}$ such that:

- $A\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{b}$
- $\| \mathbf{z} \|_2 \leq \|\mathbf{x} \|_2$ for all $\mathbf{x}$ that satisfy $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$. (i.e. $\mathbf{z}$ is the minimum norm solution to the undetermined system.

Example, if system is $x + y = 1$, numpy.linalg.lstsq would return $x = .5, y = .5$.

#### How does dgelsd work?

The routine `dgelsd` computes the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD) of A.

I'll just sketch the idea behind using an SVD to solve a linear system. The singular value decomposition is a factorization $U \Sigma V' = A$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix where the diagonal entries are known as singular values.

The effective rank of matrix $A$ will be the number of singular values that are effectively non-zero (i.e. sufficiently different from zero relative to machine precision etc...). Let $S$ be a diagonal matrix of the non-zero singular values. The SVD is thus:

$$ A = U \begin{bmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} V' $$

The [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$ is given by:

$$ A^\dagger = V \begin{bmatrix} S^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} U' $$

Consider the solution $\mathbf{x} = A^\dagger \mathbf{b}$. Then:

\begin{align*}
A\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} &= U \begin{bmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} V' V \begin{bmatrix} S^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} U' \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b} \\ &= U \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} U' \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b}\\
\end{align*}

There basically two cases here:

1. The number of non-zero singular values (i.e. the size of matrix $I$) is less than the length of $\mathbf{b}$. The solution here won't be exact; we'll solve the linear system in the least squares sense.
2. $A\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0}$

This last part is a bit tricky... need to keep track of matrix dimensions and use that $U$ is an orthogonal matrix.

#### Equivalence of pseudo-inverse

When $A$ has linearly independent rows, (eg. we have a fat matrix), then:
$$A^\dagger = A'\left(AA' \right)^{-1}$$

For an undetermined system, you can show that the pseudo-inverse gives you the minimum norm solution.

When $A$ has linearly independent columns, (eg. we have a skinny matrix), then:
$$A^\dagger = \left(A'A \right)^{-1}A'$$

Comment: dgelsd uses SVD but R lm uses QR?

Comment: @hxd1011R's `lm` uses QR factorization by default but you can specify alternatives.

Comment: The dgelsd documentation in the code file says it uses QR.