# scikit-learn linear regressor digests perfectly collinear features?

Tags: regression, linear-model, scikit-learn, covariance, multicollinearity

I am currently running this little piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.linear_model as skl_lm

X = np.random.normal(size = 1000)**2
y = X + np.random.normal(size = 1000)

Y = np.array([ [ X[i], X[i] ] for i in range(1000) ])

model = skl_lm.LinearRegression().fit(Y,y)
print(model.coef_)
print(np.dot(Y.transpose(),Y)/999)
```

It just creates 1000 squares of a normal random variable $X$, and uses it to create another linearly correlated variable $y$, accounting for some noise. Then creates a matrix of features $Y$, where the two features are actually both $X$. Then it tries to fit $y$ over $Y$. The model actually generates something, while the second print shows that the correlation matrix between columns of $Y$ is singular. How is `sklearn.linear_model` digesting this singular matrix? I believe it should not be able to determine the coefficients, as it should invert the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Internally](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L547) `sklearn` uses `scipy.linalg.lstsq` function for finding solutions to linear equation, which is the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372559/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-linalg-lstsq-and-scipy-linalg-lstsq) as `numpy.linalg.lstsq`, and its innerworkings are described in this post: [How does NumPy solve least squares for underdetermined systems?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240573/how-does-numpy-solve-least-squares-for-underdetermined-systems)